# Languages in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, localization, translate

my web (laravel 5.2 framework) has two language. I have to  2 button

```
<button> English </button>
<button> Japan </button>
```

How can I switch language of website when click button. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, finally I found my answer at http://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale